# How do I create nested categories in a Database?

Tags: database, nested, categories

I am making a videos website where categories will be nested:

e.g. Programming-> C Language - > MIT Videos -> Video 1
     Programming -> C Language -> Stanford Video - > Video 1
     Programming -> Python -> Video 1

These categories and sub-categories will be created by users on the fly. I will need to show them as people create them in the form of a navigable menu, so that people can browse the collection easily.

Could someone please help me with how I can go about creating such a database?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317322/optimized-sql-for-tree-structures

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081951/my-sql-multiple-category-subcategory-subcategory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quassnoi said :

> You should use either nested sets or parent-child models.

I used to implement both of them. What I could say is:

Use the nested set architecture if your categories table doesn't change often, because on a select clause it's fast and with only one request you can get the whole branch of the hierarchy for a given entry. But on a insert or update clause it takes more time than a parent child model to update the left and right (or lower and upper in the example below) fields.

Another point, quite trivial I must admit, but:
It's very difficult to change the hierarchy by hand directly in the database (It could happen during the development). So, be sure to implement first an interface to play with the nested set (changing parent node, move a branch node, deleting a node or the whole branch etc.)

Here are two articles on the subject:

- [Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/)
- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Last thing, I didn't try it, but I read somewhere that you can have more than one tree in a nested set table,  I mean several roots.

Answer (score 19):

Make a categories table with the following fields:

- CategoryID - Integer
- CategoryName - String/Varchar/Whatever
- ParentID -       Integer

Your ParentID will then reference back to the CategoryID of its parent.

Example:

```
CategoryID CategoryName ParentID
---------------------------------
1          Dog          NULL
2          Cat          NULL
3          Poodle       1
4          Dachsund     1
5          Persian      2
6          Toy Poodle   3
```

Comment: How do i construct a query to create the navigation from such a table ? Is there an easy way?

Comment: Jake: I don't know how you would do your own navigation, but the standard way would be to display a single level (such as the top level) first using a query like "select * from tblCategories where ParentID is NULL" so you would get Dog and Cat. Then when you click on dog you could get the next level by querying "Select * from tblCategories where ParentID = 1" because 1 is the categoryid of Dog. And then you continue in the same manner the further down you drill.

Answer (score 5):

You should use either `nested sets` or `parent-child` models.

`Parent-child`:

```
typeid parent name

1      0      Buyers
2      0      Sellers
3      0      Referee
4      1      Electrical
5      1      Mechanic
```

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   group IN
        (
        SELECT  typeid
        FROM    group_types
        START WITH
                typeid = 1
        CONNECT BY
                parent = PRIOR typeid
        )
```

will select all buyers in `Oracle`.

`Nested sets`:

```
typeid lower  upper  Name
1      1      2      Buyers
2      3      3      Sellers
3      4      4      Referee
4      1      1      Electrical
5      2      2      Mechanic
```

```
SELECT  *
FROM    group_types
JOIN    mytable
ON      group BETWEEN lower AND upper
WHERE   typeid = 1
```

will select all buyers in any database.

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916367/database-model-structure) for more detail.

`Nested sets` is more easy to query, but it's harder to update and harder to build a tree structure.

Answer (score 5):

From the example in your question it looks like you'd want it to be possible for a given category to have multiple parents (e.g., "MIT Videos -> Video 1 Programming" as well as "Video -> Video 1 Programming"), in which case simply adding a ParentID column would not be sufficient.

I would recommend creating two tables: a simple Categories table with CategoryID and CategoryName columns, and a separate CategoryRelationships table with ParentCategoryID and ChildCategoryID columns. This way you can specify as many parent-child relationships as you want for any particular category. It would even be possible using this model to have a dual relationship where two categories are each other's parent and child simultaneously. (Off the top of my head, I can't think of a great use for this scenario, but at least it illustrates how flexible the model is.)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i wanted. As an example i would want that an "assembly language primer video" should be listed in both "reverse engineering basics" as well as "programming languages".

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a basic parent-child relationship:

```
Category (ID: int, ParentID: nullable int, Name: nvarchar(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to store the parent_id of the table is to have it nested within the ID
e.g

100000 Programming
110000 C Language
111000 Video 1 Programming
111100 C Language
111110 Stanford Video

etc..so all you need it a script to process the ID such that the first digit represents the top level category and so on as you go deeper down the hierarchy

Comment: This is quite an interesting way. Do you have any ideas how to query such data though?

Comment: Doesn't this limit you to 10 top level items 0-9? What's the reason for using the zeros, are you using a set number of integers which limits the number of  possible children? How would you insert new items and update them?