# my sql multiple category-subcategory-subcategory

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

```
category subcategory subcategory
jewelry   body       nose ring,arm ring,ear ring 
          men        ring,ear ring
```

I have multiple `category->subcategory->subcategory` so how will be the table for this in MySQL?

Comment: Remember that this is not a forum, so "help me plz asap" and "thanks" lines only pollute the question content. As you can see, question that [deserve an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) are usually answered very fast.

Comment: Are you potentially going to have more than three levels of category, or only the three included in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Structure your Table like this:

```
Id   Category    ParentId
1     Jewelry     NULL
2     Body          1
3     nose ring     2
4     arm ring      2
5     ear ring      2
- 
-
```

This is called Self-Referencing Table i.e. `ParentId` columns contains either `NULL` or value from the `Id` column of same table.

so whenever you have to know all the direct `subcategories` of a given `category`, you simply create a query like :

```
   Select * from CategoryMaster where ParentId = 2;
```

doing this you will get all the sub-categories for the sub-category `Body`.

Now, the best part about this data-structure is that you can have n-levels of sub-categories for any given sub-category and same single table with 3 columns (at minimum) will do.

Comment: I was thinking to this table, but look at the exemple provided by sanjay, ear ring have 2 parents and I think it have to be only one category row

Comment: so what, you can have two entries for ear ring both with different parentId

Comment: imho the 2nd subcategory (rings) has 1,n relation with 1st subcategory (men, body).

Comment: So there will be 2 differents category row for the same real category

Comment: but i having 10 Category  & for each Category  i having 1 subcategory & those 10 subcategory 
so how will i proceed.
http://www.etsy.com/browse/jewelry/body?ref=br_nav_new_1
pls look at the end you will see the structure here

Comment: @sanjay, first, you have to organize your data like this, then, you can loop through the rows of this table, and a clever loop can build a Tree structure out of it for you.

Comment: What do you think of two tables ? One for store categories (categoryId, categoryName) and another for the tree structure (categoryId, parentId). Just have to be careful of your tree structure to prevent loop.

Comment: that would only make things complex, see i've made a [simple algorithm](http://pastebin.com/tQD2yU1k) in C# to create a tree structure. it works perfectly to n-levels with just single table. you should try to extract the algorithm out of it

Comment: A self referenced table doesn't permite multiple parents for the same row, just allow 1-n relation, not n-n. Depends on the need.

Answer (score 0):

While designing the schema for hierarchical data you should consider the requirement. If You are going to have just one level of category means one parent and then its subcategory then the way you are storing the data is best. But if you are having unknown level of subcategory or more than one subcategory then consider The Nested Set Model. 
Refer this link  http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/